# Grammar clarification on a sentence

Tags: american-english, writing-style

I am using this statement in my job application's cover letter.

" Kindly requesting to consider my career interest and immediate availability."

Mentioned sentence is showing it as grammar error.

What exactly i have to do to rewrite the sentence?

Comment: There's not necessarily a grammar error, but the sentence is gobbledygook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is missing a subject.  That's why your computer doesn't like it.

You could say "Please take note of my career interests and immediate availability."

Comment: Thank you, @user344654 , it is very helpful. I will make sure to have a subject in  the sentences to avoid such errors